# Помогите найти ошибки в коде x = [тут хранятся числа] n = 10 for i in range(n): if x[i] > 0: s += i print(s/n)

Tags: python

```
x = [ ]
n = 10
for i in range(n):
   if x[i] > 0:
      s += i
print(s/n)
```

Comment: А что нужно найти - сумму индексов???

Answer (score 1):

например

1. в списке `x` меньше, чем 10 элементов, то будет ошибка
2. не проинициализирована переменная `s`

например такой код был бы более корректным:

```
x = [ ]
s = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
   if x[i] > 0:
      s += i
print(s/len(x) if len(x) != 0 else 0)
```

ну и более короткая версия:

```
print(len([v for v in x if v > 0]) / len(x) if len(x) != 0 else 0)
```